# Ubuntu 16,04 GUI only updates when switching to and from tty

Tags: 16.04, screen, gui, tty

Since this morning my screen is frozen except for my mouse; clicking on an application shows the wheel spinning while it is loading and hovering over certain parts of the screen changes the cursor but the results of my actions don't show up. If I switch to one of the terminals with ctrl+alt+1 for example and back with ctrl+alt+7 the changes are there, e.g. the application has started and is visible. My second monitor only works with tty, for the GUI it is not detected. The sound works properly. I did not install any upadtes yesterday, and my installation has worked properly for a few years until now. Booting Windows on the same laptop works as well as starting ubuntu in recovery mode.

I updated all my packages and reinstalled ubuntu-desktop but no luck so far.   What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from Nouveau driver to the 384.130 nvidia driver solved the issue. I don't know if it somehow switched or the Nouveau driver stopped working.